# PHP - Convert a bytes array in stream

Tags: php, arrays, stream

as in .NET I have the possibility to do:
`byte[] myByteArray = new byte[10];
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);`

How could I convert a byte array in a Stream using **PHP**?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could write the data into a [`php://memory` stream](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), but that's not a particularly common thing to do, and there may well be easier ways of accomplishing the end result. Can you provide any more context?

Comment: Thank you for your answer: I have an array like 
Array ( [1] => 54 [2] => 50 [3] => 51 [4] => 48 [5] => 49 [6] => 49 [7] => 49 [8] => 49 )
and I need to do the following thing done in .NET :

Dim ms As MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(inBytes, 0, inBytes.Length)
            Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(ms, algh.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)

in PHP.